# How do I sort Linked list based on the length of strings?

Tags: c++

I coded in many ways but I am unable to do so.Can anyone help me solving this?

```
void LinkedList::Sort(){
    Node* p = NULL;
    Node* q = first;
    Node* r = first->next;

    while(r!=NULL) {

        if(q->data.length() > r->data.length()) {
            p = q;
            q = r;
            p->next = p->next->next;
            q->next = p;
            r = q->next;
        } else {
            q = q->next;
            r = r->next;

        }
        q = q->next;
        r = r->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making a swap function. It's easier to think about than worry about `->`'s everywhere.

Comment: input: sandeep
fsadudif
kjhs
sandeeeep
jggkj
kcg
sa
zz .  output: sandeep
fsadudif
kjhs
sandeeeep
jggkj